# "Carrot of profits"

Tags: phrases

What does the phrase, *carrot of profits*, mean? The [context](http://books.google.com/books?id=9ELvBMCyKKwC&lpg=PA83&ots=XQD_Q-67H4&dq=nd%20for%20smaller%20companies%2C%20using%20the%20%2a%2acarrot%20of%20profits%2a%2a%2020%20years%20away%20isn%E2%80%99t%20likely%20to%20sway%20VCs%20who%20can%20see%20no%20further%20than%20three.&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=false) is

> And for smaller companies, using the **carrot of profits** 20 years away isn’t likely to sway VCs who can see no further than three.

*A little of profit*?

Comment: By the way the grouping is "carrot of (profits 20 years away)", not "(carrot of profits) 20 years away."

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Important point to point out. +1

Comment: what can I say - that the original text from the book

Answer (score 9):

Donkeys may be encouraged to undertake forward motion either by hitting them on the rear end with a stick or by dangling a carrot ahead of their front end. Hence the expression *stick or carrot* means to offer either punishment or reward to those we would wish to act in a certain way. In your example, the prospect of profits 20 years down the line is presented as being akin to tempting a donkey with a carrot.

Comment: I've often wondered if donkeys are so stupid they willingly walk round a treadmill all day just because an unreachable carrot has been hung in front of them. Sounds like an issue to explore on skeptics.se!

Comment: @Fumble I don't know about donkeys, but my dog movements could be used to provide energy for a whole city when running after its tail.

Comment: Thank's! I can't get the metaphor about the carrot in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Simplified, the sentence becomes:

> "Using the carrot isn't likely to sway VCs."

The *carrot* is essentially an incentive, shortened from the metaphor, "the carrot and the stick."

What the sentence says is that VCs of smaller companies--who are looking for a quick profit and exit in perhaps just three years down the line--cannot be swayed by the *possibility of profit* (i.e. the carrot) 20 years later.

Answer (score 2):

It means reward as in the phrase "the carrot and the stick", which refers to the use of a carrot as a reward and (hitting with) a stick as punishment for a horse or other draft animal.