# Where does the expression "carrot and stick" come from?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I thought it was a Tantalus-like metaphor, suggesting a donkey will walk toward a carrot dangling from a stick forever, given the stick is tied to the donkey. It seems to be used as reward versus punishment metaphor. Why would the average Joe find a carrot a reward?

Comment: Answer is [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/44572/12918)

Comment: The whole point of a metaphor is that you take something that applies to X, say donkeys, and then apply it to Y, say humans. That's what "metaphor" *means*.

Comment: Sure, I just thought the metaphor was to the leadability of a donkey-like person, not the suitability of a carrot as the reward.

Comment: ..and btw, I see Wikimedia lists my understanding as a variant, called "carrot on a stick." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick

Answer (score 1):

I don't support cruelty to animals, but [this story](http://www.mikelockett.com/stories.php?action=view&id=174) describes the stick in the "carrot and stick" idiom. The stick does not refer to the stick that the carrot is dangling from.

The average Joe might not find a carrot sufficiently attractive, but the donkey is not an average Joe. Also, the carrot is a stand in for anything that Joe would find sufficiently motivating, it's not necessarily a real carrot.

Comment: Er,I like the link, but there's no carrot in this particular story!!

Comment: The person posing the question seemed to assume that the stick from which the carrot dangles is the stick referred to in the metaphor. Even though it lacked the carrot, the story to which I linked was intended to provide an example of the stick, even though the carrot happened not to be preesent in the story.

Comment: As a closer reading of your answer would have told me!